# setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component

Tags: reactjs

**Update**

Found the problem in my HTML. I was causing a scripts to be inserted twice to my `<body>` by having an extra `<?php $this->endBody() ?>` in my `Yii` layout.

---

I've seen other solutions to this error message in SOF, but I think mine is different.

The moment I call `setState` in the `$.get` callback, I will get the error message.

I have removed all the code that I commented while testing that didn't solve the error.

As you can see in `componentDidMount` I called `setState` twice. The first is fine, but the second call throws the error message.

Does it has anything to do with the `$.get` method?

**Component**

```
let GridComponent = React.createClass ( {
        getInitialState ()
        {
            return {
                total_page  : 0,
                next_page   : 0,
                current_page: 0,
                items       : []
            }
        },
        componentDidMount() {
            this.setState ( {
                total_page: 1
            } );
            $.get ( '/entry/getdata?page=' + this.state.current_page, ( d ) => {
                if ( typeof d !== 'undefined' ) {
                    this.setState ( {
                        total_page: 1
                    } );
                }
            } );

        },
        componentDidUpdate() {

        },
        mapDataToGridItems( d ) {

        },
        loadMore() {

        },
        fetchData() {

        },

        render ()
        {
            return (
                <div className="grid-gallery-container">

                </div>
            )
        }

    } )
    ;
ReactDOM.render (
    <GridComponent />, document.getElementById ( 'grid-component-root' )
);
```

Comment: First `setState` inside `componentDidMount` is not necessary, you can set `total_page` in initial state.

Comment: The actual code was to set more data. I just changed it for testing. But I found the problem. Will update my question.

Comment: Yes, it has no sense to use some `setState` inside `componentWillMount` or `componentDidMount`. And you could also move your `get` request to `componentWillMount` - it will be called earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you got this error when you try to call `setState` for unmounted component - this often happens with callbacks.
To prevent this you should use flag (set it in `getInitialState` and reset in `componentWillUnmount`). Or (much better) use `Redux` to exclude all I/O operations and async calls from your visual component.